# Limits and continuity: $\lim_{ x\rightarrow0} {\frac{ax+bx^3}{x^2}} = 2$. Find the values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help

$$\lim_{ x\rightarrow0} {\frac{ax+bx^3}{x^2}} = 2$$
Find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: l'Hopital this.

Comment: This question can't have a finite limit, unless $a$ is $0$, because it simplifies to $\frac{a}{x}+bx$, and as $x \rightarrow 0$, then $bx \rightarrow 0$ regardless of what $b$ is, and $\frac{a}{x}$ either converges to $zero$ or to $\pm \infty$. But even when the limit is finite, it is $0$, not $2$. There is something wrong, or $a$ and $b$ are functions of $x$. Please check your question before you post.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lim_{ x\rightarrow0} \frac{ax+bx^3}{x^2}
&=\lim_{ x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^2(\frac{a}{x}+bx)}{x^2}\\[6px]
&=\lim_{ x\rightarrow0} \left(\frac{a}{x}+bx\right)\\[6px]
&=\begin{cases}
  \pm\infty&\text{if $a\neq 0$ (*)}\\[6px]
  0 &\text{if $a=0$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

<sup>(*) Depending on the sign of $a$ and if it is $x\to 0^+$ or $x\to 0^-$.</sup>

Then, if $a\neq 0$, the limit doesn’t exist. Therefore $a=0$, but in this case, the limit is $0$. The limit is never $2$.

Comment: I like your answer, so I took the liberty of reformatting it for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the current limit, both the denominator and numerator equal zero. Use L'Hopital's rule. This then becomes

$\lim_{ x\rightarrow0} {\frac{a+3bx^2}{2x}} = 2$

Does that help?